# Pandas: Pass MULTIPLE conditions in the ON parameter in pandas.merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to merge two pandas DataFrames if key match and column id don't match?

testchunck1.csv:

```
excel1 user_id public_key
0      Mark    key1
1      Rhonda  key2
2      Clara   key3
3      Riley   key4
```

testchunck2.csv:

```
excel2 user_id public_key
0      Ron     key2
1      Russel  key1
2      Dwyane  key2
3      Abrax   key4
```

output_df:

```
           userid_left  public_key  userid_right
    0      Mark         key1        Russel 
    1      Rhonda       key2        Ron 
    2      Rhonda       key2        Dwyane
```

**Note**: `key4` matches in both DFs but the ID(3) is same, so it is not in the output

My code:

```
test1Excel = pd.read_csv("testchunk.csv")
test2Excel = pd.read_csv("testchunk2.csv")

df = pd.merge(test1Excel,test2Excel, on='public_key', how='inner', suffixes = ('_left','_right')).dropna()
```

1. Tried using `.filter()` to filter out the rows after merge but
   unsuccessful.
2. Tried reading each and every row of excel to check if
       IDs match but that took a lot of time.
3. Tried passing a condition
           within the on parameter itself but it doesn't allow that

Hence turning to SO.

Comment: So you want to match, only if the respective row number does not match, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If row number/id doesn't match, and key matches, it is in the output.

Comment: _Tried using .filter() to filter out the rows after merge but unsuccessful._ To me that sounds like a decent solution, why didn't it work? Also, **please share your data in a format that is easier for other people to use**, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.merge(test1Excel.loc[test1Excel["public_key"].str.startswith("key")].reset_index(),test2Excel.loc[test2Excel["public_key"].str.startswith("key")].reset_index(), on='public_key', how='inner', suffixes = ('_left','_right')).dropna().query("index_left!=index_right").drop(columns=["index_left", "index_right"])
```

Outputs:

```py
  excel1 user_id_left public_key excel2 user_id_right
0      0         Mark       key1      1        Russel
1      1       Rhonda       key2      0           Ron
2      1       Rhonda       key2      2        Dwyane
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I forgot to mention that it is also matching on empty values for public key or public keys that don't start with 'key'. So my excel size is getting too big. Could I do `.query("str('public_key').startswith('key')")` to filter out rows that have keys in it that start with 'key'?

Comment: I tweaked my answer a bit - now you have this extra condition included

Comment: Thank you. I actually figured it out before your updated answer. In a preprocessing step, I did this: `test1Excel = test1Excel[test1Excel['public_key'].str.startswith("key")]`. But with that and your solution, I get an error saying: `ValueError: cannot mask with array containing NA / NaN values`.  Do you have any idea on this error? Note: I just got this error so I am yet to search it online.

Comment: Try: ```test1Excel = test1Excel.loc[test1Excel['public_key'].fillna("").str.startswith("---")]```